# convert a line of strings into a list of strings without getting newline character

Tags: python, string, list

i wish to give

```
input = '1;Go home;Do assignment; go to class'
```

and get `output = ['1','Go home','Do asssignment','go to class']` . with split i get \n and also splitlines does not give required output.

Comment: Looks like you should split by `;`

Answer (score 5):

You want to `split` by `;` and `strip` whitespace from the beginning and ending of the resulting strings. `strip` will also get rid of trailing newline characters, if there are any.

```
>>> inp = '1;Go home;Do assignment; go to class'
>>> [x.strip() for x in inp.split(';')]
['1', 'Go home', 'Do assignment', 'go to class']
```

Also, don't use `input` as a variable name, it's a builtin.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the newline, not splitting, you can use `strip()`:

```
string = '1;Go home;Do assignment; go to class\n'
print string.strip().split(';')
```

In case the input is inconsistent with the spaces like in your example (some semicolons may follow by a space: "go to class") you can do:

```
import re
string = '1;Go home;Do assignment; go to class\n'
print re.split(r';\s*', string.strip())
```

Comment: Still has the blank before 'go' :)

Comment: I think using list comprehension likes timgeb's answer may be more simple

Comment: @heroandtn3 and I feel that using a simple regex is not really complicated :) Now seriously, timgeb's answer is a good one, probably even performs better cause it doesn't use regex, but I don't like the explicit iteration over the tokens and "cleaning" each one of them. That's just a matter of personal taste. If you like it better - use it, but as a good programmer you should know the other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried split, but when I use this:

```
myInput = '1;Go home;Do assignment; go to class'
myInput.split(";")
```

I get this as my output:

```
['1', 'Go home', 'Do assignment', ' go to class']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call rstrip on your input string to remove the trailing \n then run your split.